# Error in installing Bugzilla on Windows

Tags: windows-7, bugzilla

I am trying to install Bugzilla 4.2.4 on Windows 7 OS.

I have completed the following steps:

1. Installation og Apache Server 2.2
2. Installation of Active perl 5.16
3. Installation of MySQl 5.6
4. Installing Perl Modules needed for Bugzilla tool.

After completing the above steps I have run CheckSetup.pl through command prompt.

I am facing the following error after that:

> "InnoDB is disabled your MySQL installation. Bugzilla requires InnoDb
>   to be enabled. Please enable it and then re-runchecksetup.pl".

Can anyone please help in moving further with the installation.

Comment: Did you enable InnoDB ? belongs to superuser.com / serverfault.com

Comment: How do we actually check if Innodb is enabled.

Comment: I have checked My.Ini file for skip-innodb and even when I run Show Engines in MYSQL command prompt I could see InnoDB as default gngine

Comment: if you are sure InnoDB is enabled, run `checksetup.pl`

Comment: When I run checksetup.pl then only I am facing that issue: "InnoDB is disabled your MySQL installation. Bugzilla requires InnoDb to be enabled. Please enable it and then re-runchecksetup.pl".

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable *InnoDB* in my.cnf and restart the service

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb